# Package Operation Failed. Installation or removal failed

Tags: 12.04, package-management, software-installation

I'm new to linux so excuse my lacking experience. Anytime I try to install anything, including just running the updater, I get an error saying `Package operation failed` the details button shows this:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%  
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 12%%    
Extracting templates from packages: 25%%    
Extracting templates from packages: 38%%   
Extracting templates from packages: 51%%   
Extracting templates from packages: 64%%  
Extracting templates from packages: 76%%  
Extracting templates from packages: 89%%  
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%  
Preconfiguring packages ...

Extracting templates from packages: 12%%  
Extracting templates from packages: 25%%  
Extracting templates from packages: 38%%  
Extracting templates from packages: 51%%  
Extracting templates from packages: 64%%  
Extracting templates from packages: 76%%  
Extracting templates from packages: 89%%  
Extracting templates from packages: 100%%  
Preconfiguring packages ...  
(Reading database ...   
(Reading database ... 5%%  
(Reading database ... 10%%  
(Reading database ... 15%%  
(Reading database ... 20%%  
(Reading database ... 25%%  
(Reading database ... 30%%  
(Reading database ... 35%%  
(Reading database ... 40%%  
(Reading database ... 45%%  
(Reading database ... 50%%  
(Reading database ... 55%%  
(Reading database ... 60%%  
(Reading database ... 65%%  
(Reading database ... 70%%  
(Reading database ... 75%%  
(Reading database ... 80%%  
(Reading database ... 85%%   
(Reading database ... 90%%dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'libqt4-svg': Input/output error
Error in function:
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess there's something missing below `Error in function:`? If yes, please add.

Answer (score 0):

libqt4-svg is a flashplugin-installer package; try an update with the fix option or upgrading the package from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update -f
sudo apt-get upgrade libqt4-svg
```

If that doesn't work, your solution may be listed on the man page for apt-get.  Here's how to view it and a few to try:

```
man apt-get
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Next, try rebooting and then an update via terminal:

```
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get update
```

If that doesn't work, take a look at your software sources.  In particular, look for old packages you may want to remove from the Other Software tab.

```
click the Dash Home
type Software Sources and hit Enter
from the top menu: Edit/Software Sources
```

This may also answer your question: [update and upgrade ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335072/update-and-upgrade-ubuntu-11-10).